# Looking for a Z-Wave compatible wall plug with Australian/NZ pins

Tags: automation

I am using Fibaro server (HC3) for Automation.

I have been using the Aeotec wall plugs (for floor lamps) but they have becoming more and more unreliable, even after updating the firmware.

The Fibaro wall plug looks good, but I am not convinced that it comes with the right pins.  In all the images, the pins are round, whereas I need them angled-flat for Australia / New Zealand.